# Cucumber V4 [io.cucumber] is not identifying @Given/When/Then and giving error "The import cucumber.api.java.en.When cannot be resolved"

Tags: cucumber

I am migrating from Cucumber Version 1.2.4 [`<groupId>info.cukes</groupId>`] to V.4.2.2 `<groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>`. After this, Cucumber Framework is not able to identify `@Given/When/Then` annotations and given error – The import `cucumber.api.java.en.Given/When/Then` cannot be resolved

Eclipse suggesting to add below dependency. But my thought is when I am migrating to Cucumber V4(`io.cucumber`) then why shall I add dependency of V1.2.4(`info.cukes`). Can someone suggest which is the correct dependency I shall add under V4 i.cucumber. which import i shall add to fix this issue. Can it be resolved without adding `info.cukes` -> `cuucmber-java`(1.2.4)

```
    <dependency>
    <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
    <artifactId>cucumber-java</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.4</version>
    </dependency>
```

Below is the list of dependencies I have added under POM.xml. All are io.cucumber dependencies.

```
   <dependency>
                <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
                <artifactId>cucumber-core</artifactId>
                <version>4.2.2</version>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
            <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-java</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.2</version>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
                <artifactId>cucumber-junit</artifactId>
                <version>4.2.2</version>
                <scope>test</scope>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
                <artifactId>cucumber-jvm-deps</artifactId>
                <version>1.0.6</version>
                <scope>provided</scope>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
                <artifactId>gherkin</artifactId>
                <version>6.0.14</version>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
                <artifactId>mockito-all</artifactId>
                <version>1.10.19</version>
                <scope>test</scope>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
                <artifactId>cucumber-testng</artifactId>
                <version>2.0.0</version>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
                <artifactId>cucumber-picocontainer</artifactId>
                <version>2.1.0</version>
                <scope>test</scope>
            </dependency>
```

Please help me to understand how this error can be resolved under cucumber v4. I do not want to use info.cukes maven id as it does not have V4. So please guide

Comment: Please remove `cucumber-core`, `cucumber-jvm-deps`, `gherkin` and `cucumber-picocontainer`. They're transitive dependencies and will be provided by your dependencies. Then run `mvn clean install` and reimport your project in your IDE.

Comment: Hey, thank you for guidance. I do have following dependencies. but still each Given, When & Then are not recognized with in step definition class. When i hove mouse on annotations, eclipse is not showing any import in suggestion. I am surprised what could be the issue. There are 26 errors of same type for each annotation so i would not be able to execute using mvn clean install until error does not get resolved.

Comment: Hey @mpkorstanje, any thought what shall be done.

Comment: Hey @mpkorstanje, can you please share your experience. What could be the issue while migrating from info.cukes to io.cucumber v4 to resolve mentioned error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have resolved the issue and sharing correct set of dependency. Please add JUnit/TestNG based on your framework requirement.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
    <artifactId>cucumber-java</artifactId>
    <version>4.2.3</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
    <artifactId>cucumber-junit</artifactId>
    <version>4.2.3</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>

<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/junit/junit -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>junit</groupId>
    <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
    <version>4.12</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>

     <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.cucumber/datatable -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
    <artifactId>datatable</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.12</version>
</dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.cucumber/cucumber-testng -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
    <artifactId>cucumber-testng</artifactId>
    <version>4.2.3</version>
</dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.cucumber/cucumber-picocontainer -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
    <artifactId>cucumber-picocontainer</artifactId>
    <version>4.2.3</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

Comment: You shouldn't need `datatable` or `junit`, they're both transitive dependencies. Everything else looks good.

Answer (score 1):

Maven looks stopped the `<groupId>info.cukes</groupId>` cucumber-java, instead of using `<groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>`.

So, from above version 4.7.0 of (`<groupId>io.cucumber</groupId><artifactId>cucumber-java</artifactId>`), there is no longer support for `cucumber.api.java.en.Given/When/Then`.

You can use `import io.cucumber.java.en.Given(/When/Then)` replacing it.

Answer (score 0):

I too faced this issue. After replacing cucumber.api.java.en.Given/When/Then
with
import io.cucumber.java.en.Given(/When/Then)

the feature file was running the mapped methods